# Bracha on Unloading and raising up animals

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, animals, tractate-brachot

Does one make a bracha over the mitzvot of unloading an exhausted animal, or raising up a collapsed animal?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is a universal opinion, but the following two sources would indicate that there is no bracha recited upon unloading/raising (פריקה וטעינה).

**1)** In the article for this mitzva in the web site for the Encyclopedia Talmudit, the footnotes [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94#cite_note-29) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94#cite_note-41) quote the ב**על העיטור** that there are those who say that no bracha is recited since each of these מצוות עשה are also connected to a לאו.

We can see this implied in the language of the pesukim for each mitzva:

> שמות כג:ה - כִּי תִרְאֶה חֲמוֹר שֹׂנַאֲךָ רֹבֵץ תַּחַת מַשָּׂאוֹ **וְחָדַלְתָּ מֵעֲזֹב לוֹ** עָזֹב תַּעֲזֹב עִמּוֹ

> דברים כב:ד - **לֹא תִרְאֶה** אֶת חֲמוֹר אָחִיךָ אוֹ שׁוֹרוֹ נֹפְלִים בַּדֶּרֶךְ **וְהִתְעַלַּמְתָּ** מֵהֶם הָקֵם תָּקִים עִמּוֹ

Also discussed in that article are whether a לאו exists only for פריקה or is there one even for טעינה.

**2)** The source listed [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=41868&rid=12004) indicates that brachos are only recited on mitzvos that are בינו לבין עצמו but not on mitzvos that are dependent on others: תלויה (בדעת) אחרים, such as tzedaka and bikur cholim and returning a lost object.  Perhaps one can extend this to the mitzvos of פריקה וטעינה since even if the animal has no *daas*, then it still maybe depends on *daas* of the animal's owner.